# OutOfMemory when creating Base64 string in java?

Tags: java, base64, out-of-memory

I used ostermillerutils library to create base64 string but I get OutOfMemory error if the image is heavy. If the image I try to convert is a simple image, the code is working fine.

```
public String createBase64String(InputStream in) {
    //collect = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        for(int readNum; (readNum = in.read(buf)) != -1; ) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getInstance().debug("XML createBase64String: IOException");
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();

            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ;
            }
        }
    }
    byte[] ba = bos.toByteArray();
    String coded = Base64.encodeToString(ba);
    return coded;
}
```

I also tried doing this but the base64 was incorrect when I tried to decode it.

```
public void createBase64String(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    //collect = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int readNum = 0;

    try {
        while((readNum = in.read(buf)) != -1)  
         {    
            smtp.addBase64(Base64.encodeBase64String(buf));
         }  
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getInstance().debug("XML createBase64String: IOException");
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Please suggest solutions for JDK 1.4 and also for later versions of Java.

Comment: Then change your strategy and don't encode everything in memory, or give more memory to your JVM. What's your question?

Comment: is there a need to load whole content into memory? that's why it's causing outofmemory.

Comment: how can I not load the content into memory? can you please give me a sample code? (sorry noob here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem by using javabase64-1.3.1.jar library.

```
OutputStream fos2 = FileUtil.getOutputStream(base64FileName, FileUtil.HDD);
InputStream  in2 = FileUtil.getInputStream(fileName, FileUtil.HDD);
Base64.encode(in2, fos2);
in2.close();
fos2.close();
```

I stored the base64 string to a text file first.

```
public void createBase64String(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int readNum = 0;
    smtp.addBase64("\t\t");

    try {
        while ((readNum = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            baos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
            smtp.addBase64(baos.toString());
            baos.reset();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        LogUtil.error("Sending of Base64 String to SMTP: IOException: " + ex);
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
            baos.close();
        }
    }

    baos = null;
    buf = null;
}
```

then send each line to smtp's socket outputstream.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to write the encoded content straight into a file then use the following code

```
public void encode(File file, OutputStream base64OutputStream) {
  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
  OutputStream out = new Base64OutputStream(base64OutputStream)
  IOUtils.copy(is, out);
  is.close();
  out.close();
}
```

`IOUtils` class from Apache Commons IO.

**EDIT**
Since you want to do it using `BufferedWriter`, use it as follows

```
 OutputStream out = Base64OutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream()); 
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
 IOUtils.copy(is, bw);
```

Comment: I don't need to write it to a file. I need to send the string via SMTP.

Comment: @pmark019, so you can write the content to the smtp sockets' outputstream

Comment: 'BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(smtpSocket.getOutputStream(), "8859_1"));' can you teach me how to do it with bufferedWriter?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is that you're having to manipulate too much data in memory when you read the entire image. One fix would be to increase the Java heap size until you have enough memory, but that would just be avoiding the problem rather than solving it.

A better option would be to look at a streaming implementation of a Base64 encoder. This would mean you're only working on a subset of the image at any time. I believe that `Base64OutputStream` from Apache Commons would do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

From Java 8 onwards, there is a simple way to implement base64 encoding in an output stream with one line of code and no external dependencies:

```
   import java.util.Base64;

   OutputStream os = ...
   OutputStream base64 = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(os);
```

`Base64` also provides other flavors of base64 encoder; see javadocs:

- [`Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)
- [`Base64.Encoder.wrap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#wrap-java.io.OutputStream-)